# Homebrew casks are not updating, how can I fix this?

Tags: homebrew

```
System Software Overview:

      System Version: macOS 12.0.1 (21A559)
      Kernel Version: Darwin 21.1.0
```

I am a newbie on MacOS. Most of the time I use Linux and tend to keep my software fresh and updated. On Linux it is quite easy - you run a simple command (`apt update && apt upgrade` for example) and it updates everything possible, include the kernel itself!

I want something similar for MacOS. I have installed `homebrew` package manager and with its help I have installed my favorite programs.

```
$ brew --version
Homebrew 3.3.7-22-g5fb34c8
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 3dedb040d32; last commit 2021-12-09)
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision dc3c9f0e1e; last commit 2021-12-09)
$ brew list
==> Formulae
ant@1.9         curl            graphite2       libde265        libtiff         mbedtls         
...
php@7.3         theora

==> Casks
1password       adoptopenjdk8       dbeaver-community   google-chrome       ngrok           slack           transmission        zoom
adoptopenjdk        alt-tab         docker          iterm2          phpstorm        telegram-desktop    visual-studio-code
```

Until this moment everything went just fine. I turned off "Automatically check for updates" setting for every single program, I have installed. I don't want update each program manually and don't want to know when new update has been released. All I want - once a week do whole system update and that is it.

In a few weeks I decided to do such system update. I found many formulas which has higher version than I had installed:

```
$ brew info --cask phpstorm
phpstorm: 2021.3,213.5744.279 (auto_updates)
https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/
/usr/local/Caskroom/phpstorm/2020.3.3 (122B)
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/blob/HEAD/Casks/phpstorm.rb
==> Name
JetBrains PhpStorm
==> Description
PHP IDE by JetBrains
==> Artifacts
PhpStorm.app (App)
==> Analytics
install: 645 (30 days), 1,785 (90 days), 6,826 (365 days)
$ brew info --cask alt-tab
alt-tab: 6.29.0 (auto_updates)
https://github.com/lwouis/alt-tab-macos
/usr/local/Caskroom/alt-tab/6.26.0 (120B)
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/blob/HEAD/Casks/alt-tab.rb
==> Name
AltTab
==> Description
Enable Windows-like alt-tab
==> Artifacts
AltTab.app (App)
==> Analytics
install: 2,595 (30 days), 5,972 (90 days), 17,086 (365 days)
```

So, let's update them:

```
$ brew update
Updated 3 taps (homebrew/cask-versions, homebrew/core and homebrew/cask).
==> Updated Formulae
snakemake
==> Updated Casks
bitwarden               subsync                 syncovery               tableau-public          tandem                  taskade                 teamviewermeeting       textbar
propresenter-beta       sweet-home3d            tabby                   tableau-reader          tap-forms               td-agent                telavox-flow
$ brew update --cask
Already up-to-date.
$ brew upgrade --cask
$ brew upgrade
```

Nothing happened...

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As said by Melonee in the comments, Homebrew Cask by default won't automatically update apps with built-in update function. If you want to do so you have to run:

```
brew upgrade --greedy
```

According to `man brew`:

```
--greedy
       Also include casks with auto_updates true or version :latest.
```

Beware that in some rare case, applications will store user data in the `.app` folder. Upgrading them via Homebrew Cask will uninstall and reinstall them, deleting associated user data. (See comments)

Comment: IMHO, better point out that Homebrew Cask by default won't automatically update apps with **built-in update** function / utility / etc. Since Homebrew Cask upgrade apps by **removing** and **reinstalling** `.app` (excl. data in `~/Library/Application Support`, etc), you may lose data for some apps like MultiMC.app which stores data inside its `.app` folder. I lost all my game saves for once. Although it's rare, there's certainly possibility of encountering such problem.

Comment: @Melonee Thank you for the clarification. I've modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: It works! And it resets the configs. Do I have any options to have smooth experience updating all my apps with a single command without such drawbacks?

Comment: You can choose to let your applications to auto-update themselves and keep all your configs, or to update all of them in one command line. But at this point, I don't think you can have both.