# Homebrew won't install from casks

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, install, homebrew

I've just wiped & reinstalled my M1 Macbook Pro (Monterey 12.4), and at some point during setup Homebrew has stopped working when installing from cask - the download completes, then nothing. It doesn't even return to the prompt.

For example, if I try to install VLC:

```bash
brew install --cask vlc
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
==> Updated Formulae
Updated 2 formulae.

==> Downloading https://download.videolan.org/vlc/3.0.17.3/macosx/vlc-3.0.17.3-arm64.dmg
######################################################################## 100.0%
```

... and then silence.

If I `^C` and try again, I get:

```
brew install --cask vlc
==> Downloading https://download.videolan.org/vlc/3.0.17.3/macosx/vlc-3.0.17.3-arm64.dmg
Already downloaded: /Users/adam/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/409341b2af745d1aeb51a7bcf0fa728f37a3cb0323b662988fcbd4b2d6c3021c--vlc-3.0.17.3-arm64.dmg
```

I assume it's a permissions issue, but I'm not sure where to start.

My Homebrew version:

```bash
Homebrew 3.4.11
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision ea77abc722f; last commit 2022-05-31)
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision c858075186; last commit 2022-05-31)
```

Comment: Did you run `brew doctor` and fix any relevant issues found?

Comment: Why do you assume it's a permissions issue?  What is the shell doing, while it's sitting there producing no output?

Answer (score 1):

I love the FAQ for this sort of issue.

- https://docs.brew.sh/Troubleshooting

> Run `brew update` twice and `brew doctor` (and fix all the warnings)

If you don’t know how to fix one warning, feel free to drop it on the comments or maybe another thread if needed.

Also, casks are not easy so I avoid them for most setups. For instance, you [need to pass a greedy flag to update them](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/433639/5472), and it’s really a delete and reinstall which can cause data loss. Make sure you have a backup of your Mac before proceeding, please.